# How to pass an enum that I created from view to controller using FormCollection in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

So now I can retrieve a string and integer

by doing this for string

```
 LastName = formCollection["LastName"]
```

and for int

```
Amount = int.Parse(formCollection["Amount"])
```

My problem now is for enum. I tried this, still have an error

```
  Issuer = Enum.Parse(formCollection["Issuer"]);
  Issuer = Enum.Parse(typeof(Issuer), formCollection["Issuer"]);
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: an explicit convertion

Comment: you should have added the error message in the question that saves other users time to figure out the actual problem

Comment: okay I will, next time, thanks again

Comment: You should never use `FormCollection`. Bind to your model! (and its all handled automatically - the `M` in MVC is for Model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I know but i'm using sdk model... don't know how bind it, if the database is in third party...

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Create a view model containing a property `Issuer Issuer`, int Amount, string LastName` etc (and use the strongly type `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to it and then add a parameter for that model in the POST method, then map it to your data model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to explicitly cast the result,as [`Enum.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method returns back instance of type `Object`, so you will need convert back to type of specific Enum type in this case `Issuer`, so you just need to add explicit casting like:

```
Issuer = (Issuer)Enum.Parse(typeof(Issuer), formCollection["Issuer"]);
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot Ehsan,